# Why can't I pass a trait to a Scala function and call it: response[A: T](r: A) = { r(value) }

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions, traits

I'm trying to implement a generic `response` function that takes an `Int` and an object, then calls `apply(e: Int)` on the provided object (which will return a new instance). Here's what I have so far:

```
trait GPResponse {
    abstract def apply(error: Int)
}

trait GPResponseMapping {
    def response[A: GPResponse](error: Int, instance: A) = { (resultCodeFor(error), instance(error)) } // Make a tuple of code and GPResponse instance
    ...
```

Which generates these compiler errors:

```
[error] GPResponseMapping.scala:68: utility.GPResponse does not take type parameters
[error]     def response[A: GPResponse](error: Int, instance: A) = { (resultCodeFor(error), instance(error)) }
[error]                   ^
[error] GPResponseMapping.scala:68: A does not take parameters
[error]     def response[A: GPResponse](error: Int, instance: A) = { (resultCodeFor(error), instance(error)) }
[error]                                                                                             ^
```

What I'm trying to do is create tuple from the combination of the error code and an instance of the response object. The response object takes the error code as a constructor argument (`apply()` argument) and returns an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah... OK, figured it out. Apparently I have to call the `apply()` method directly, as in `instance.apply(...)` which is a bit startling, but it works:

```
trait GPResponse {
    abstract def apply(error: GPError): GPResponse
}

trait GPResponseMapping {
    def response(error: Int, instance: GPResponse) = { (resultCodeFor(error), instance.apply(error)) }
    ...
```

If anyone can explain why I'm not able to use `instance(error)` in this context, I'd appreciate the explanation. Thank you!

Comment: `instance(error)` should be fine - what goes wrong when you try that? The error in your original question was about the `[A: GPResponse]`, not about the `instance(error)`.

Comment: `instance(error)` is a compile-time error, but calling `instance.apply(error)` works just fine. I was trying to use type parameters to get around this... but the `instance.apply(error)` works for me.

Answer (score 3):

When you write this:

```
def response[A: GPResponse](error: Int, instance: A) = {
```

the compiler expands it to this:

```
def response[A](error: Int, instance: A)(implicit $ev0 GPResponse[A]) = {
```

However, since you defined `GPResponse` like this:

```
trait GPResponse {
```

It doesn't take a type parameter, and so you can't write `A : GPResponse`.

Comment: So is what I'm trying to do impossible? I started with simply: `def response(error: Int, instance: GPResponse) = { (resultCodeFor(error), instance(GPError.errorForCode(error))) }` but this complains that `apply(): Unit` is not defined, and I can't get around _that_ problem...